# What's the purpose of writing html statement this way?

Tags: html, comments, rendering

[image]

Above is the html source.

[image]

Here comes the corresponding rendered text.

I assume that `<!-- -->` is used for comments. Why was it used in the example with empty comments? And why were separated letters used in place of a single word *aiken*?

EDIT: here's the source page https://cs.stanford.edu/faculty

Comment: Guess: It could be to hide that word from search engines (albeit ineffectively)

Comment: Another guess: JavaScript could detect each letter as a different text node. Not sure what could be the purpose though.

Comment: That is in a column called email so maybe to hide it from bots. Though doesn't seem to have any actual full email addresses in that column anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Reason: Server side code generation.**

This may be generated by a server application that sometimes adds info to each letter, for example 'letter ranking' with server generated comments in the source, sometimes done for debugging purposes by programmers.  In this case no information is present so the output just ends up with an empty comment.

Comment: I agree that the comments may be generated by server application since there's no reason for them to write empty comments manually.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible reason:  Avoid harvesting of email addresses.

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde) said in the comments, one thing is for bypassing the search engines and malicious ones, which harvest on the email addresses, as it is an email column.

Check out this: [How do spammers harvest email addresses?](http://www.private.org.il/harvest.html)